# How to get a fixed number of rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have 4 rows in database like these.

```
 |____A____|____B_____|
 |   a1    |    b1    |
 |   a2    |    b2    |
 |   a3    |    b3    |
 |   a4    |    b4    |
```

But I need to display 10 rows by added `NO` column to get serial number for each row like these

```
 __NO__|____A____|____B_____|
   1   |   a1    |    b1    |
   2   |   a2    |    b2    |
   3   |   a3    |    b3    |
   4   |   a4    |    b4    |
   5   |         |          |
   6   |         |          |
   7   |         |          |
   8   |         |          |
   9   |         |          |
  10   |         |          |
```

How to query by sql server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a9dd/1

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS [NO]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [NO]+1 FROM CTE1 WHERE [NO]<10
),
CTE2 AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN, A,B 
FROM  YOURTABLE
)

SELECT C1.[NO],A,B
FROM CTE1 C1 LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.[NO] = C2.RN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way without using recursive cte and `LEFT JOIN`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1024f/2/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT 
        NO = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A, B), A, B
    FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.n, NULL, NULL
    FROM (VALUES
        (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20)
    )t(n)
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NO)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    rn AS NO, A, B
FROM CteFinal
WHERE rn < = 10
```